# cannot find symbol for an existing variable

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        int [] array= {4,5,7,1,5,4};
        for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++) {
            int min;
            min=array[0];
            if(array[j]>min) {
                min=array[j];
            }
        }
        System.out.print(min);
    }
}
```

can you help me why min cannot be found?

Comment: To gain a more complete understanding of the answers given here, you should learn about so-called "scope of a variable". I'm sure your textbook has a very good explanation. You can also use google to find out more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to access `min` from a different scope from where it was declared.

You are declaring it inside your `for`-loop:

```
for(int j=0; j < array.length; j++) {
    int min;
    min=array[0];
    if(array[j]>min) {
        min=array[j];
    }
} // min can't be used after this.
```

However, you are using it outside of the loop. `int min` is only valid within the scope of the `for` loop block (the `}` that closes the loop ends the block that `min` is accessible in).

Move the `min` declaration outside of the loop and it should work.

```
int min = array[0];
for (int i : array) {
    if (i > min) {
        min = i;
    }
}

System.out.println("The min is: " + min);
```

---

I made your code a little more syntactically sweet with [Java's `for`-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

---

Also, is there a logic error in your code? You call the variable `min` but you are assigning numbers **larger than `min`** to min. Sounds like you're looking for max value, not minimum?

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `min` outside of the loop (because of scope):

```
int [] array= {4,5,7,1,5,4};
int min = array[0];// initialize min outside the loop.
for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++) {
    //min=array[0]; If you leave this here, you will 'reset' min each time
    if(array[j] < min) { // use "<" so that min will be the minimum
        min=array[j];
    }
}
System.out.print(min);
```

Also, you should not have `min=array[0];` in your loop; this wil cause `min` to "reset" back to `array[0]` at each loop iteration.  Instead, initialize it outside the loop.  Finally, it looks like your code will set `min` to the largest element in `array`.  To fix, reverse the comparision in the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Min is being declared within the for-loop. If you move the declaration outside, it should work fine.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] array= {4,5,7,1,5,4};
        int min=array[0];
        for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++) {
            if(array[j]>min) {
                min=array[j];
            }
        }
        System.out.print(min);
    }
}
```

Comment: That may or may not work. You're resetting `min` to `array[0]` each iteration.

Comment: Yeah, just fixed that after I saw all the new answers

Answer (score 1):

Min is local to the for loop

```
    int [] array= {4,5,7,1,5,4};
    int min = array[0];
    for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++) {
        if(array[j]>min) {
            min=array[j];
        }
    }
    System.out.print(min);
```

Comment: That may or may not work. You're resetting `min` to `array[0]` each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

`min` was declared inside the for loop.

Remove `int min;` and put the following outside the for loop:

```
 int min=0;
```

Since it's a local variable it must be initialized.

Also move `min=array[0];` outside the for loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because the scope of the min variable lasts inside of the for block.

Comment: That may or may not work. You're still resetting `min` to `array[0]` each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `if(array[j]<min) min=array[j];` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just moving `min` out of the for loop doesn't help. It will overwrite `min` everytime. Also move `min=array[0];` out of the for loop.